# Unable to use SSL certificate for my domain

Tags: ssl, certificate, cpanel

I use sslforfree.com to generate SSL certificate. I set www.example.com and example.com and generate certificate. I set certificate on `cPanel`. After that I see following error message and domain is unsecure in browser:

> The SSL certificate also supports this domain, but this domain does
>   not refer to the SSL website mentioned above: www.example.com

Comment: *"I set www.example.com and example.com..."* - Where did you set it? Are they Subject Alternate Names (SAN)? Please provide the URL to the server. We need to examine the server's certificate.

Comment: You may need to simply add the DNS reference record or whatever—I think it's the ACME record or something like that. I used Let's Encrypt and you have to renew it every 90 days or so but certbot and some mounting and file copying automation helps with that and for a `*.<domain>`.com type cert too.